# Windows 8 pro: backup to pendrive connected to router usb

Tags: usb, backup, usb-flash-drive, wireless-router

I have a Windows 8 pro pc, I'd like to connect a pendrive to my router (it supports this, the pen is seen as a network share) and use it to backup my pc with the standard MS backup tool.

Will it work? 
I read that when Win 8 was released the backup (file history) could use just a fraction of the available space and that you cannot use a full disk or partition to backup, is this true even today?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up network drives as target, check this microsoft article,
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/set-drive-file-history

It is mandatory to use external drive for the target.

I believe you would like to know about the Windows Image Backup. Yes, full disk backups are supported in Windows8. To backup, open the "Control Panel -> Windows 7 File Recovery applet" and click the "Set up Backup" button.  Also, you can launch "sdclt.exe" from the Command Prompt or enter it "Run" to start this applet.

In Windows8.1, Image backup is available in the "File History" settings page in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I made a recover image on usb key and it works. I tried to configure file History but it seems that it is not possible to use the full external drive capacity for backup, in the settings there is a limit, if I remember well it is 20% of the drive capacity. Is there a way to override this and tell to Windows "this is your backup drive, use all available space for file History"? Something like Apple's Time machine.